# Rooting citrus cuttings

Tags: trees, citrus, cuttings

I've rooted many roses and more recently, some some Eureka lemons. But have no luck with Persian limes. They want to grow fruit rather than roots. I have three cuttings right now, one with eight buds and one with four and one that looks like it's not doing anything. This is not the first time I've tried rooting limes and they've always either died or tried to produce fruit rather than leaves or roots. Is that common with limes?

If I snip off the tiny fruit buds, will that help them root?

Comment: I can't give you advice on rooting persian limes, but I tell you not to let them flower.  When they start to make flower buds pinch them off.  Don't let it spend energy on making flowers and fruit.   Plant that think they are dying often flower, trying to produce seeds before they die.  Pass on genetics.  You mustn't let it put energy into dying, but to live.

Comment: Thanks. I did snip off the flower buds right away. I root these things in clear plastic, usually just cutting off the top of a water bottle and poking some holes in the bottom. That way I can see if there are roots developing. There are now, after almost 3 months, some roots showing, but as of yet no new leaf growth. The two leaves I left on each cutting are however, still dark green, so that's good.